# ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'keras.utils'

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to create a custom datagenerator in keras -

```
class DataGenerator_cnn(keras.utils.Sequence):
'Generates data for Keras'
def __init__(self, list_IDs, labels, batch_size=5, dim=(30,128,157),
             n_classes=1, shuffle=True):
    'Initialization'
    self.dim = dim
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.labels = labels
    self.list_IDs = list_IDs
    self.n_classes = n_classes
    self.shuffle = shuffle
    self.on_epoch_end()
```

However , it shows error upon execution

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'keras.utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/**init**.py)

I am using the latest version of keras (2.5.0) on google colab. Please help

Comment: You should share more of codes to help you. Anyway you may trying to import ``Sequential`` from a wrong path like: ``from keras.utils import Sequential``. But you should try to import like this: ``from keras import Sequential``

Comment: This worked for me: 
`from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence`

Answer (score 2):

You could try it using `tf.keras` instead keras

`import tensorflow.keras as keras`